# Unable to set Storyboard Segue Identifier in Xcode 5.1 because Attributes Inspector is blank

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I keep getting this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver
>   () has no segue with identifier
>   'joinGameWelcomeScreenSegue''

Which is because in my storyboard I can't set the identifier for the storyboard segue

After I select the segue in the Attributes Inspector, the entire field is blank (see image below). I have tried restarting Xcode, my computer and performing project clean and build cleans. I also have another Storyboard for the iPad version in the same project which is working correctly. So I'm not exactly sure what is happening.

When one of the buttons (create or join) is clicked. I disable that button, execute some code and will not segue to the next scene until some data is retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the "Storyboard Segue" panel is hidden? If so, over on it and "Show" should appear.